# rich:dataScroller: set focus

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have the next `<rich:dataTable>` and `<rich:dataScroller>` example:

```
<h:form id="sampleForm">
    <rich:dataTable id="capitalsTbl" value="#{capitalsBean.capitals}" var="cap" rows="5">
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{cap.state}"/>
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{cap.name}"/>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>

    <rich:dataScroller id="capitalsScroller" for="capitalsTbl" oncomplete="console.log('focus');" />
</h:form>
```

I'm using **JSF 2** and **RichFaces 4.1.0.Final**.

It is necessary to **implement the focus belavior**: as soon as a user presses the next/previous link the focus should stay on the pressed link. If the pressed link becomes "disabled" (actually, it becomes a span because of the RichFaces implementation) then the focus should move to the another one (next or previous depending on disabled link).

My suggestion is to set the focus **inside the "oncomplete" method**.

The question is: **how can I determine which link has been pressed by the user**?

Thank you.

Comment: Using data model I always know current page number. You can store previous page number too. Comparing those 2 numbers you can define action (pressed link).

Comment: You have 'event' object when processing oncomplete, but that 'event' object does not have anything useful (as far as I know). All the cool info (event source, etc.) were lost when onclick processing completed. So, one potential way is to add an onclick handler and store it's 'event' object somewhere (e.g. globally in window object), and then access it in the oncomplete handler.